# How to apply validation in angular 2 dropdown (Model driven Approach)

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

If user click in submit button it do not validate the dropdown .i want to validate form if user do not select any value and form state will be invalid in that case.in my case i have disabled the submit button if form is invalid but in this case it is showing valid form.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <label>User</label>
                <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedReferralUser" formControlName="users" required>
                  <option value="-1" selected disabled>--select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let user of users" value= {{user.id}}>{{user.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Create Order

```
export class CreateOrder implements OnInit {
  public createOrderForm: FormGroup;
  public selectedWorkshop = 1;
  public customerId: number;
  public nationalStates: any;
  public selectedState = "New Delhi";
  public workshops: any;
  public selectedPhoneCode = 91;
  public phoneCC: any;
  public loading: boolean = false;
  public enableSubmit = false;
  public userType: any;
  public selectedUserType="";
  public users: any;
  public selectedReferralUser="";


  public ADDRESS_TYPE = {
    PICKUP: "pickup",
    DELIVERY: "delivery"
  };

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private createOrderService: CreateOrderService,
    private weDoShoesCMSService: WeDoShoesCMSService,
    private listItemService: ListItemService,
    private itemDetailsService: ItemDetailsService,
    private googleMapService: GoogleMapService
  ) {
    this.enableSubmit = false;
    this.customerId = Number(localStorage.getItem('customerid'));
    this.nationalStates = this.listNationalState();
    this.phoneCC = this.weDoShoesCMSService.listCountry();
  }


  public searchBox: any;
  public filterDateType: FilterDateType;
  public states: State[];
  public order: Order;
  public showTimePicker: boolean;
  public pickup_date: any;
  public pickSlots: any;
  public selectedPickupSlot = 1;

  ngOnInit() {
    const phoneRegex = `^[2-9]{2}[0-9]{8}$`;
    this.createOrderForm = this.fb.group({
      pickSlots: this.listPickupTimeSlot(),
      pickup_date: ['', Validators.required],
      customer_name: [localStorage.getItem('customerName'), [Validators.required]],
      phone: [Number(localStorage.getItem('customerPhone')), Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(phoneRegex)])],
      addressType: this.initAddressTypeFormGroup(),
      items: this.fb.array([]),
      workshops: this.listWorkshop(),
      userType: this.listUserType(),
      phoneCC: [''],
      users: ['']
    });

    this.addItem();
    this.subscribeAddressTypeChanges();
    this.setAddressType(this.ADDRESS_TYPE.PICKUP);


      }

  initItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      tax_percentage: [''],
      est_delivery_date: [''],
      est_delivery_time: [''],
      parentServices: [''],
      services: [''],
      brands: [''],
      sizes: [''],
      products: [''],
      discounts: [''],
      is_express_delivery: [''],
      is_packing: [''],
      confirmed: [''],
      coupon: ['']
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are you creating the form object show that code too . You don't need to use `Ng`Model1

Comment: The `required` *attribute* in HTML can go in component, like this: `users: [-1, Validators.required]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `ngModel` in model-driven approach? That is template-driven approach.

You can simply do this

```
private myForm : FormGroup;

let formControl: FormControl;
        formControl = new FormControl('Add your drop down values here', Validators.required);
        this.myForm.addControl('users', formControl);
```

.html

```
<select formControlName="users">
            <option value="-1" selected disabled>--select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]= {{user.id}}>{{user.name}}</option>
</select>

<alert *ngIf="myForm.controls['users'].invalid" type="danger">Please select value</alert>
```

Comment: How do i get selected value

Comment: `this.myForm.value['users'];`

Comment: ok i will do it. But how i will validate my dropdown that is my question.Can i manually set the form in invalid state.

Comment: `Validators.required` is already added to form control, and if you check `myForm.controls['users'].valid` somewhere it will show you `false` if no option was selected from the dropdown. Updated the answer for that.

Comment: If i use -1 than it shows this form is valid.in my case i can not use " " ,so is there any way to solve this problem.

Comment: Can any one please provide the proper validation of dropdown using model driven approach

Comment: Setting default value to " " is the better approach. Why can't you use that?

Comment: Can i access child component control values by taking the reference of parent form in the child component template. can i do that

Comment: createOrderForm .controls.items.products

Comment: i have a input group in child component itemForm and it have the property products

Comment: If you have managed to add the child components control to parent's form `createOrderForm` then definitely you can access them in child component.